# Javascript fetch results Pending in React

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

I want to fetch some data on my React page and it gets the result correctly.

However, regardless of the fetch result, its Promise status is still Pending.

[Promise still in Pending](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITPbf.png)

And here's my code:

```
const config = require("./config.json");

function App() {
  const getSongs = (keyword) => {
    return fetch(
      `https://api.genius.com/search?q=${keyword}&access_token=${config.genius.token}`
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => json.response.hits)
      .catch((err) => err);
  };
  console.log(getSongs("faded"));
  return <div className="App"></div>;
}

export default App;
```

I already tried async/await, but it didn't work.

Is there any solution for this situation?

Comment: For side effects & async operations in React you need to use an [`useEffect` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). You may also need a [state hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html). Just go through the docs

Comment: `I already tried async/await, but it didn't work` How? Because it is clearly the solution. It says the Promise is still pending because you are `console.log`ging it immediately, long before it resolves. It will resolve later, inside the `.then()`